# Localhost on Mac and view on Android

Tags: php, android, macos, nginx, localhost

I have PHP web on Mac and I want to see it on Android.

- Mac OSX: 10.9.3
- IP: 192.168.1.107
- server: nginx/1.4.7

If i write to Android browser IP my Mac, then browser show `It works`. But my project is on URL example.dev (hosts: `127.0.0.1   example.dev`).

If i write to Android browser `192.168.1.107/example.dev`, then browser show `File not found.`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test your website locally with a domain name, try adding

```
192.168.1.107 example.dev
```

to your android's host file, assuming you have Root.

You also need to set your webserver to listen on `example.dev`